# What is the purpose of the requirement on mollification radius?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, convolution

On page 66 of "Sobolev Spaces (Adams ed2)" in the proof of Lemma 3.16
(Mollification in $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$), it is mentioned that $\varepsilon < {\rm
dist}(\Omega', \partial\Omega)$. However, I cannot see where this condition is
used in the proof. Could you please help explain this, thank you! The proof
given by the book is given as follows:

Lemma (Mollification in $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$): let $J_{\varepsilon}$ be defined as
$J_{\varepsilon}(x) = \varepsilon^{-n} J(\frac{x}{\varepsilon})$ and let $1 \leq
p < \infty$ and $u \in W^{m,p}(\Omega)$. If $\Omega'$ is a subdomain with
compact closure in $\Omega$, then $\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}}
J_{\varepsilon}*u = u$ in $W^{m,p}(\Omega')$.

Proof: Let $\varepsilon < {\rm dist}(\Omega', \partial\Omega)$ and $\tilde{u}$ be the
zero extension of $u$ outside $\Omega$. If $\phi \in \mathscr{D}(\Omega')$,
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega'} J_{\varepsilon}*u(x)D^{\alpha}\phi(x){\rm d}x &=
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\Omega'}
\tilde{u}(x-y)
J_{\varepsilon}(y)
D^{\alpha}\phi(x){\rm
d}x {\rm d}y \\
&= (-1)^{\lvert \alpha \rvert} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\Omega'} D^{\alpha}_x
u(x-y) J_{\varepsilon}(y) \phi(x) {\rm d}x {\rm d}y \\
&= (-1)^{\lvert \alpha \rvert} \int_{\Omega'}
J_{\varepsilon}*D^{\alpha}u(x)\phi(x){\rm d}x
\end{align*}
Then $D^{\alpha} J_{\varepsilon}*u = J_{\varepsilon}*D^{\alpha}u$ in the
distributional sense in $\Omega'$. Because $D^{\alpha}u \in L^p(\Omega)\;
\forall 0 \leq \lvert \alpha \rvert \leq m$, we have
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \lVert D^{\alpha}J_{\varepsilon}*u -
D^{\alpha}u \rVert_{p,\Omega'} = \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \lVert
J_{\varepsilon}*D^{\alpha}u - D^{\alpha}u \rVert_{p,\Omega'} = 0
$$
Thus $\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}} \lVert J_{\varepsilon}u - u
\rVert_{m,p,\Omega'} = 0$.

Comment: Can you please make your question self-contained, by including the context of the proof (e.g. a picture)?

Comment: @T.Bongers Thanks for your reminding! I have added the original lemma and proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption is implicitely used here:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\Omega'} \tilde{u}(x-y) J_{\varepsilon}(y) D^{\alpha}\phi(x){\rm d}x {\rm d}y
&=
\int_{B_\varepsilon(0)}\int_{\Omega'} \tilde{u}(x-y) J_{\varepsilon}(y) D^{\alpha}\phi(x){\rm d}x {\rm d}y
\\
&= (-1)^{\lvert \alpha \rvert} \int_{B_\varepsilon(0)}\int_{\Omega'} D^{\alpha}_x u(x-y) J_{\varepsilon}(y) \phi(x) {\rm d}x {\rm d}y \\
&= (-1)^{\lvert \alpha \rvert} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\Omega'} D^{\alpha}_x u(x-y) J_{\varepsilon}(y) \phi(x) {\rm d}x {\rm d}y
\end{align*}
If $\varepsilon$ would be to large, $x-y$ might not belong to $\Omega$ and you cannot use integration by parts.

Comment: I understand. If $\varepsilon$ is not limited, $u(x-y)$ will be meaningless after the integration by parts. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, $\tilde u(x-y)$ is defined to be zero for $x-y \not\in \Omega$. Hence, there might be a jump at the boundary of $\Omega$ and you cannot use integration by parts.

Comment: Then I see. I'm now self-studying Sobolev Spaces with an engineering background. So my question may seem too naive to you. Many thanks for your explanation!